# screen shaking in chrome browser

Tags: php, jquery, css, google-chrome

A user of a web page has reported that the web page is shaking while viewing in Chrome.

This is a php page using lot of jquery and css.

It is not occurring any of the browsers on my end and so quite perplexed on where to begin.

I read somewhere it can be fixed using meta tag but that did not help. This is what I tried

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

I am now thinking if it is a css issue but not sure where to begin. Thank you for any tips/solutions.

Comment: This happened to me once with a gap of 3 pixels in my resize strategy. Try using the browser responsive tool and resize the page with 1 pixel at a time until you get the same result. Unfortunately, we cant help you without a reproductible scenario. Your question does not qualify for stackoverflow.

Comment: My guess is the screen shacking occurs at a certain page width in combination with a user interaction like a hover or something. The item takes more space and falls off the mouse and because it's off, it goes back to the original state and loops in a shaking fashion. But in anycase, we can't help cause we don't have HTML or an URL to wk with.

Comment: Apparently It happens only when the user types in the input or texture

Comment: Alright. At least you were able to reproduce it. You should be in a better shape of finding the solotion. If you honestly need help, post the html, css and script related to that portion in a code snippet. But Now that you know where it happens, you should be fine ;-)

Comment: Don't know where is it happening and so not sure which snippet to share

Comment: Then this post is at an impasse... You can't share a link, you can't share code. How are we supposed to help? Good luck in solving this. Unfortunately, I am back to my first statement. Your question does not qualify for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Applied the following fix.

There were multiple occurrences of style attribute

```
height: 20em; overflow: auto
```

I've changed to

```
height: 20em; overflow-y: scroll
```

This has fixed the issue!

Hopefully this will help someone who is looking for an answer. Thank you for all support, much I truly appreciate.